# Encoding the character '‰' returns "ï¿½"in Python after a subprocess.check_output

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, subprocess

I'm creating a sublime text plugin to use [lua-fmt](https://github.com/trixnz/lua-fmt) and format lua code automatically on save. It's almost done, except some characters like '‰' return weird results like "ï¿½" after the formatting.

What I did to format the code was create a file with the old code and use the lua-fmt program, by calling it with `subprocess.check_output` like in the excerpt below:

```
file = open("formattingAux.lua","w")
file.write(self.view.substr(file_text))#text from saving file
file.close()

output = subprocess.check_output("luafmt formattingAux.lua", shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
```

I've tried to use `subprocess.Popen()` as well, but it yielded the same result. If I run the luafmt program on a file it produces the correct result, that's why I think there is a problem with the `subprocess.check_output` encoding.

I also tried diferent encodings with no positive result.

Thanks!

Comment: which encoding use lua-fmt? Did you tell python about that encoding? Also with your open: always specify the encoding. Make explicit your choice.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Using the explicit encoding for my file worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GiacomoCatenazzi pointed out, I was not explicitly enconding my auxiliar file, which made the lua-fmt not know the strange character, changing the open method to `wd`and encoding it as *UTF-8* worked perfectly!